# Properties are undefined within a decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to call a function that that has a decorator attached to it. What it does is run every `x` seconds which works just fine, however, when I try to log the properties in the function they output `undefined`, but in the constructor it displays the proper class.

If I call another function that is in the class, the function gets called, the issue just seems to be when accessing properties.

Here are a few of the ways I have tried to call the method:

```js
export function Repeat(interval: number, delay: number = 0) {
  return (target: any, prop: any, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {

    timer(delay * 1000, interval * 1000)
      .pipe(
        tap(i => descriptor.value.call(target, i)),
        tap(i => target[prop].call(target, i)),
        tap(i => target[prop].bind(target)(i))
      )
      .subscribe();

  };
}
```

Here is how I am implementing the decorator:

```js
export class MyClass {

  constructor(private readonly v: Item) { 
    console.log(this.v); // outputs: typeof Item
  }

  @Repeat(1)
  repeat(count: number) {
    console.log(this.v); // outputs: undefined
    this.testFunc(); // runs the function
  }

  testFunc(){
    console.log('test function');
  }
}
```

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-b2tg2e?file=index.ts) example

### Edit

After playing for a bit, I can see that I can do this:

```js
export function Repeat(interval: number, delay = 0) {
  return function (target: any, prop: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function (this: GameObject, ...args: any[]) {
      const t = timer(delay * 1000, interval * 1000)
        .pipe(map<number, boolean>(i => originalMethod.apply(this, [i])))
        .subscribe();
    };
    return descriptor;
  };
}
```

Then when I call it in the class the repeater works:

```js
export class MyClass {

  constructor(private readonly v: Item) { 
    this.repeat(0);
  }

  @Repeat(1)
  repeat(count: number) {
    console.log(this.v); // outputs: typeof Item
  }
}
```

However, this is not what I want to resort to, I would like the function to be called automatically and not manually.

Comment: Interesting, I tried `const gi = new Item(); const gmc = new MyClass(gi);` and `console.log(gi === this.v);  console.log(gmc === this);`... and both show `false`. But `console.log(this.testFunc === gmc.testFunc);` shows `true` Seems the `repeat()` is working with some other object/instance?

Comment: It' very interesting behavior. The `target` parameter of the descriptor is only a prototype object of `MyClass`, but not an instance of `MyClass` therefore `.bind` and similar functions don't help, since they only bind it to that prototype

Comment: This is also what is specified in the docs [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#method-decorators)
"The expression for the method decorator will be called as a function at runtime, with the following three arguments: ... the prototype of the class."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to solve my issue I had to use a decorator at the class level along with at the method level. Then, in the constructor I run the method on the parent class.

First import the `reflect-metadata` module:

```js
import 'reflect-metadata';
```

```
export function Component() {
  return <T extends { new (...args: any[]): any }>(target: T): any => {
    return class extends target {
      private methods: string[] = [];
      constructor(...args: any[]) {
        super(...args);
        this.methods = Reflect.ownKeys(target.prototype) as string[];
        this.runRepeater();
      }

      runRepeater() {
        this.methods.forEach((method) => {
          const { delay, interval } = Reflect.getMetadata('token', target.prototype, method) || {};
          if (!delay || !interval) return;
          timer(delay * 1000, interval * 1000)
            .pipe(map<number, boolean>((i) => super[method]()))
            .subscribe();
        });
      }
    };
  };
}
```

Here is the repeat function:

```js
export function Repeat(interval: number, delay = 0) {
  return function (target: any, prop: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    Reflect.defineMetadata('token', { interval, delay }, target, prop);
  };
}
```

Here is how it is implemented in the class:

```js
@Component()
export class MyClass {

  constructor(private readonly v: Item) { 
    console.log(this.v); // outputs: typeof Item
  }

  @Repeat(1)
  repeat(count: number) {
    console.log(this.v); // outputs: typeof Item
  }
}
```

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-74uysk?file=index.ts) example.